# How to check if array contains two specific strings in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a chat app that can have chatrooms with max two users. 
I got a collection `chatrooms` and chatroom-documents with an array field `members` that contains two user id's. 
Know before I can create a new chatroom I want to check if two specific users already got a chatroom together, so I need to query the two user id's with my documents.

In the end I just want to check if a chatroom exists and then return false then trying to create another chatroom with the same two specific user id's.

My problem is the query of the array content.

I tried with

```
chatroomsCollection.where('members', '==', firstUserID).where('members', '==', secondUserID).limit(1).get()
```

and tried

```
chatroomsCollection.where('members','array-contains', firstUserID).where('members', 'array-contains', secondUserID).limit(1).get()
```

but it doesn't work.

Is it even possible to query multiple strings with elements inside an array in noSQL?

Comment: FYI there is no such language as "NoSQL".  What you are asking is specific to Firestore.  It's a NoSQL type database, which means there are no relational queries, such as joins.

Comment: The first attempt fails because you are comparing the array members with the user id string. The second fails because you can not have two 'array-contains' in a single query, see the section about compound queries: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to query like this, you will need a different data structure.  Consider instead an object type field like this:

```
members: {
    'uid1': true,
    'uid2': true
}
```

Then you can query documents like this:

```
chatroomsCollection
    .where('members.uid1', '==', true)
    .where('members.uid2', '==', true)
    .limit(1)
    .get()
```

Comment: I agree, this is probably the way to go.

Comment: I already saw this structure in an example, but was not sure with two things whether I could implement it with this structure. 1. Can I still use `array-contains` if I want to query all the chatrooms a user is member of? 2. Do I have to perform two individual queries if the order of the strings passed in the request is the other way round?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer 1. No, not for objects.  2. No.

Comment: @DougStevenson You helped me a lot and saved me a lot of time. Thank you!

Comment: I am currently using this kind of structure but with attributes named "user1" and "user2", I need to have a query to find if there is a document which have two specific strings under "user1" and "user2". The problem is that I don't know in advance the order. So an example: I have two input strings: "Apple" and "Banana", and I want to check if this document exists - there are two options: "user1" = "Apple", "user2" = "Banana" OR "user1" = "Banana", "user2" = "Apple". Both of these situations are valid and I want to retrieve it. How would I write this query?